# Unique count list based on three columns

Tags: excel

How to get unique list based on three columns.I did this with two columns.I want add another column for this (Shift Column).In cell G6 I have add data validation for shift.I want find unique list on B & C columns after I select the shift from the drop down.I w2ant find unique list from b&c after I select the shift

G5 cell I have

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($B$5:$B$36&$C$5:$C$36<>"",MATCH("~"&$B$5:$B$36&$C$5:$C$36,$B$5:$B$36&$C$5:$C$36&"",0)),ROW($B$5:$B$36)-ROW($B$5)+1),1))
```

In G8:G18 column I have below

```
=IF(ROWS(G$8:G8)>$G$5,"",INDEX($B$5:$B$36&"-"&$C$5:$C$36,SMALL(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($B$5:$B$36&$C$5:$C$36<>"",MATCH("~"&$B$5:$B$36&$C$5:$C$36,$B$5:$B$36&$C$5:$C$36&"",0)),ROW($B$5:$B$36)-ROW($B$5)+1),ROW($B$5:$B$36)-ROW($B$5)+1),ROWS(G$8:G8))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In G5

```
=SUM(IF(($A$5:$A$20=$G$6),1/COUNTIFS($A$5:$A$20,$G$6,$B$5:$B$20,$B$5:$B$20,$C$5:$C$20,$C$5:$C$20)),0)
```

and in G8 etc

```
=IF(ROWS(G$8:G8)>$G$5,"",INDEX($B$5:$B$20&"-"&$C$5:$C$20,SMALL(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A$5:$A$20=$G$6,IF($A$5:$A$20&$B$5:$B$20&$C$5:$C$20<>"",MATCH("~"&$A$5:$A$20&$B$5:$B$20&$C$5:$C$20,$A$5:$A$20&$B$5:$B$20&$C$5:$C$20&"",0))),ROW($B$5:$B$20)-ROW($B$5)+1),ROW($B$5:$B$20)-ROW($B$5)+1),ROWS(G$8:G8))))
```

Adjust ranges to suit.

[image]

Comment: I want a dropdown for select shift in G6.Then after I select either i want unique list from both b & c columns.I need what are the uniqure list for shift a if i select shift a from the dropdown.

Comment: I want get what are the unique for shift A  and B separate. your formula doesn't  contain any relationship to drop down cell.F6,After I select shift A i need unique list for sales rep and the product only belong to shift A.Please see the above image.I dont need combine shift name with column B &C.I need see unique list accrding to the shift I select inF6

Comment: just change the g6 to f6 then

Comment: in your pic the dropdown is in g6 anyway. you should be able to adapt this to your sheet.

Comment: no i'm not opening an unknown link. it should be clear from the formula the ranges that you need to adapt.